# add class to element when hover over a separate class

Tags: jquery, css

I would like a hidden image to display when hovering over some text.  I have a page here.

https://image-hover-1.superhi.com/

My js is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
$('.text').hover(function(){     
    $('.photo').addClass('visible');    
},     
function(){    
    $('.photo').removeClass('hide');     
});
});
```

My CSS is:

```
.hide {display: none;}

.visible {display: block;}
```

Comment: You need to insert https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js (check developers tools with f11 to see errors)

Comment: When you add the `visible` class you have to remove `hide`, and vice versa. But why use two classes? Just use one `hide` class that you add or remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shorten css and js sections. you don't need toggle any class, just toggle image itself

```js
$(document).ready(function() {     
  $('.text').hover(function(){     
     $('.photo').toggle();    
    })     
});
```

```css
.photo{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="text">Hello there</p>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="photo"/>
```

Just beware of toggle whole set of images which you assign the class="photo". For this case the statement is `$(this).next().toggle();`

Answer (score 0):

Use `toggleClass` its the right tool for that kind of situation

```js
$(document).ready(function() {     
  $('.text').hover(function(){     
     $('.photo').toggleClass('visible');    
    })     
});
```

```css
.photo{display:none;}
.visible {display: block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="text">Hello there</p>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="photo"/>
```

Comment: this will show on first hover, hide on second, show on third etc.  hover accepts a second handler fyi

Comment: @BrianPatterson i think you should re read the op question also i invite you to read more about toggleClass

Comment: i know what it does.  make a fiddle if you are unsure

Answer (score -1):

```
$(".photo").hide();
$(".text").hover(function(){
      $(".photo").show();
},
function(){
     $(".photo").hide();
 });
```